# How to initialize global array after a recursion function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm having a hard time reinitializing the array arrRolled after the function steamrollArray is called. 
The goal of the function is to return an array with all the elements & without nested arrays.

For example: [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]] ===> [1,2,3,4]

When I tried initializing arrRolled before returning abc, then abc is being returned as an empty array, even though the declaration "arrRolled=[]" comes after the declaration of abc as a copy of arrRolled "abc = arrRolled.slice()"

```
var arrRolled=[];

function steamrollArray(arr) {
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    //console.log()
    if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
        let j = i;
        steamrollArray(arr[j]);
        continue;
    } else {
      //console.log("else:" + arr[i]);
      arrRolled.push(arr[i]);
      //console.log(arrRolled);
      continue;
  }
  }
  var abc = arrRolled.slice();
    //arrRolled=[];
    return abc;
}
```

Expected results:

```
console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]])) // [1,2,3,4]
console.log(steamrollArray([[["a"]], [["b"]]]));  //["a", "b"]
```

Actual results:

```
console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]])) // [1,2,3,4]
console.log(steamrollArray([[["a"]], [["b"]]]));  //[1,2,3,4,a,b]
```

Answer (score 0):

each time that your are invoking `steamrollArray` you have to nullify the `arrRolled`.

the first call for `steamrollArray` is already covered in `var arrRolled=[];`, but that is not the case for any other call.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>


<script>
var Trouble=[1, [2], [3, [[4]]]];
var Trouble2=[[["a"]], [["b"]]];






function Turn(CharZ){
 var Result=[];
 for(var i=0;i<CharZ.length;i++){
  if(!(Array.isArray(CharZ[i]))){
   Result.push(CharZ[i]);
  }else{
   Result = Result.concat(Turn(CharZ[i]));
  }
 }
 return Result;
}
var NotTrouble=Turn(Trouble);
console.log(NotTrouble);
document.body.innerHTML = NotTrouble;

var NotTrouble2=Turn(Trouble2);
console.log(NotTrouble2);
document.body.innerHTML +="<br>";
document.body.innerHTML += NotTrouble2;






</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is simple Answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to update your helper whenever you start a call, but that's awkward to do and demonstrates some of the issues with globals.  Since you need this to remain in place between your recursive calls, you cannot simply reinitialize it at the beginning of the function.  But one way that you can accomplish this is to add it as a default parameter to your function, then pass the current value to the recursive calls.  That would look like this:

```js
function steamrollArray (arr, arrRolled = []) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr .length; i++) {
    if (arr [i] instanceof Array) {
        let j = i;
        steamrollArray (arr [j], arrRolled);
        continue;
    } else {
      arrRolled .push (arr [i]);
      continue;
    }
  }
  var abc = arrRolled .slice ();
  return abc;
}

console.log (steamrollArray ([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]])) // [1,2,3,4]
console.log (steamrollArray ([[["a"]], [["b"]]]));  //["a", "b"]
```

However, there is a fair bit of extraneous code in here.  Let's see if we can simplify it.  Pulling out the unnecessary `continue` statements, inlining the local variables which are only used right after their declaration, and removing the now-redundant `slice` call, we get something cleaner:

```js
function steamrollArray (arr, arrRolled = []) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr [i] instanceof Array) {
        steamrollArray (arr [i], arrRolled);
    } else {
      arrRolled .push (arr [i]);
    }
  }
  return arrRolled;
}
```

But we can get cleaner still, using some ES6 features:

```js
const steamrollArray = (arr) => arr .reduce (
  (a, x) => [...a, ...(Array .isArray (x) ? steamrollArray (x) : [x])],
  []
)
```

But I'm afraid all of these involve too much code, unless this is a learning exercise.  Because this very function is actually [built into](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) modern JS engines (but not IE or Edge).  So really all you need is

```js
const steamrollArray = (arr) => arr.flat(Infinity)
```